# No schema specified on job or table error when using fs.createWriteStream to write JSON data to bigquery table

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, fs

Code is basically an exact copy of the bigquery API documentation:

```js
const { BigQuery } = require("@google-cloud/bigquery");
const bigquery = new BigQuery();
const dataset = bigquery.dataset("firebase_test_data");
const table = dataset.table("flattened_data");
const fs = require("fs");

fs.createReadStream("./data.json")
  .pipe(table.createWriteStream("json"))
  .on("job", (job) => {
    // `job` is a Job object that can be used to check the status of the
    // request.
    console.log(job);
  })
  .on("complete", (job) => {
    // The job has completed successfully.
  });
```

Error that is thrown is the following: No schema specified on job or table.

No idea why this is going on since it's almost an exact copy of the documentation code! I have also tried following a diffferent format such fs.createWriteStream({sourceFormat: "json"}) - resulting in the same error.

Comment: Does your data.json file contains all columns that exists on your table ?

Comment: The table is completely empty and I had just created it before attempting this. Should I add the columns to the table first :O?

Comment: Sorry, I think I missunderstood what you are trying to do here. Are you trying to insert data from the ./data.json file ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You’re getting this error since the table defined in `const table = dataset.table("flattened_data");`  doesn’t have the appropriate schema which you are passing in data.json.

I tried the following code as per the [Google documentation](https://googleapis.dev/nodejs/bigquery/latest/Table.html#createWriteStream-examples) and specified the schema of my table in BigQuery which successfully loads data into my table.

```
const {BigQuery} = require('@google-cloud/bigquery');
const bigquery = new BigQuery();
const dataset = bigquery.dataset('my-dataset');
const table = dataset.table('my-table');

//-
// Load data from a JSON file.
//-
const fs = require('fs');

fs.createReadStream('/path-to-json/data.json')
 .pipe(table.createWriteStream('json'))
 .on('job', (job) => {
   // `job` is a Job object that can be used to check the status of the
   // request.
 })
 .on('complete', (job) => {
   // The job has completed successfully.
 });
```